# warning: taking address of temporary - C++

Tags: c++

The following code is an example from a book "[Design Patterns Explained Simply](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21795152-design-patterns-explained-simply)". I tried using the suggested way of other questions but with bad results. How can I figure out this problem:

```
commands[0] = &SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble);
```

"warning: taking address of temporary"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Number
{
  public:
    void dubble(int &value)
    {
        value *= 2;
    }
};

class Command
{
  public:
    virtual void execute(int &) = 0;
};

class SimpleCommand: public Command
{
    typedef void(Number:: *Action)(int &);
    Number *receiver;
    Action action;
  public:
    SimpleCommand(Number *rec, Action act)
    {
        receiver = rec;
        action = act;
    }
     /*virtual*/void execute(int &num)
    {
        (receiver->*action)(num);
    }
};

class MacroCommand: public Command
{
    vector < Command * > list;
  public:
    void add(Command *cmd)
    {
        list.push_back(cmd);
    }
     /*virtual*/void execute(int &num)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
          list[i]->execute(num);
    }
};

int main()
{
  Number object;
  Command *commands[3];
  commands[0] = &SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble); // "warning: taking address of temporary"

  MacroCommand two;
  two.add(commands[0]);
  two.add(commands[0]);
  commands[1] = &two;

  MacroCommand four;
  four.add(&two);
  four.add(&two);
  commands[2] = &four;

  int num, index;
  while (true)
  {
    cout << "Enter number selection (0=2x 1=4x 2=16x): ";
    cin >> num >> index;
    commands[index]->execute(num);
    cout << "   " << num << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not add C as a tag to a question also tagged C++, C++11, C++14.

Comment: Please give us the exact error and the line where this error is reported.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not even sure it should be tagged c++11 or c++14 or even visual-c++.

Comment: Looks like you should be using an array or `vector` of `unique_ptr<Command>`.

Comment: Does as your other `Command`: `SimpleCommand one(&object, &Number::dubble); commands[0] = &one;`.

Comment: Are you sure that the book suggested that line of code?

Comment: If that code example is really from that book, please burn it. You should never need a member function pointer in a "simple example" of anything. The syntax is godawful and it's just a very specialized tool, especially in modern C++. Not to mention using out parameters...yuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line is the third of.

```
Number object;
Command *commands[3];
commands[0] = &SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble); // "warning: taking address of temporary"
```

In this, `SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble)` constructs a temporary, which will cease to exist at the end of the statement, and the `&` takes its address.  Hence the warning - the pointer will be dangling (pointing to an object that no longer exists).   Any dereferencing of that pointer will cause undefined behaviour.  A compiler is not required to diagnose this, but yours is doing you a favour.

Simply do as you have with other objects:  construct the object and then store its address.

```
SimpleCommand simple(&object, &Number::dubble);
commands[0] = &simple;
```

Note that this will encounter the same problem if `command[0]` is used after `simple` ceases to exist.   More realistic code (e.g. not everything within a toy `main()`, as noted by "Useless in comments) can easily have the problem of `commands[0]` continuing to exist - and being used - after the object it points to ceases to exist.    That also causes undefined behaviour - but it is less likely that the compiler will be able to recognise that and issue a warning.

Comment: Note that in general (ie, not in the toy example where everything is in main), this may suffer the same problem when `simple` goes out of scope.

Comment: @Useless - that's true.   I'll add a note to that effect shortly.

Comment: Better still, use a smart pointer: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Command> commands; commands.push_back(std::make_shared<SimpleCommand>(&object, &Number::dubble));` or the like.

Comment: @TobySpeight - that won't address the problem of `object` ceasing to exist before the `shared_ptr` destroys the contained object.

Comment: That's true - I was only looking at the `SimpleCommand`.  The ownership and lifetime of `object` does also need to be considered.

Comment: Agreed.  Although I expressed it in a different manner, that is the message of the last para I added.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble)
```

Creates something called **rvalue**. This is a temporary value that will be destroyed at the end of the statement, so you should not keep reference to it.